# XUL used in web development

Tags: xul

I am looking for some start up guidelines to share their experience on XUL development in web application. How good is the option to develop the interface in XUL ?. Can IE understand XUL interface?. I have started reading about XUL and I am liked confused a lot.

Please share your development experience on XUL development.

Thanks

Comment: you should accept more answers if you want more activity on  your questions.

Answer (score 4):

XUL is a Mozilla-only technology meaning that it will only work in Firefox and other browsers based on the Gecko engine. I have bad news for you though: Firefox 4 (meaning Gecko 2.0) disabled support for remote XUL for security reasons, so using it in web applications will no longer be possible. It was arguably a bad idea in the first place.

Comment: HTML will need to evolve further if it is to become as good as XUL was at writing applications a decade ago.

Comment: @Neil: I was writing about web applications only. Desktop applications are an entirely different beast and there I have my concerns as well.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into [Ample SDK](http://www.amplesdk.com/) UI Framework, XUL (see [examples](http://www.amplesdk.com/examples/markup/xul/views/)) is just one of the several XML-based technologies it enables across all browsers, also in IE6.

Answer (score 0):

The ZK web framework (www.zkoss.org) is based on XUL. Actually the web pages you built, using this framework, have the extension ZUL. It produces html + ajax code capable to run in all modern browsers. We are using it in my company for two years now and i have to say it changed my view about XUL.